# C# docx locating a word into Table

Tags: c#, novacode-docx

I have a word document with a huge two columns table, the first column contains a code, and the second one contains a word. In many rows the word of the second column is repeated so I need to locate all rows with repeated words. I'm using findAll() method and getting the index for every occurence of the word but I can't get the table row from that index.
Below is the code I'm using.

```
using (DocX doc = DocX.Load(path/to/file.docx)){
   Table table = doc.Tables[0];
   var ocurrences = doc.FindAll("text", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

Comment: Should you call FindAll on the table and not on the doc?

Comment: @PepitoSh the table entity has no findAll method

Answer (score 0):

You can LinQ for getting repetitive rows as:

```
var repetitive = doc.Tables.GroupBy(s => s.Word).SelectMany(grp => grp.Skip(1));
```

Note :- here `Word` is the second column

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I can't find a way to programmatically select the desired column (s.Word is the second column on table), could yo help me?

Comment: If you need CODE of repetitive Words, then  var repetitive = doc.Tables.GroupBy(s => s.Word).SelectMany(grp => grp.Skip(1)).Select(a=>a.Code);